# Multipart: Boundary not found

Tags: node.js, react-native, mongoose

I am sending image selected from Expo Image Picker and other data in Form Data and passing it through Axios to node. But Unfortunately i am getting Error: Multipart: Boundary not found.
I need help.

```
Selected Image : "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FLevelNextClient-d47662dc-9f84-4299-a322-f00845340c43/ImagePicker/dcca0023-60e3-4c31-a16d-ce01e4ea758e.jpg"
```

```
 const data = new FormData();
        
        data.append('name', name)
        data.append('email', email)
        data.append('phone', phone)
        data.append('image',
            {
                uri: image,
                name: "UserProfile.jpg",
                type: 'image/jpg'
            });
     const response = await axios.post(
            `${ConfigData.SERVER_URL}/auth/updateProfile`, 
            data,
            {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            });
```

```
    router.post("/updateProfile", fileUpload.array("file"), async (req, res) => {
      const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers});  
      var saveLocation = '';
      busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        saveLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads/videos' + filename);
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
      });
      busboy.on('finish', function() {
        (async ()=>{
         const user_id = req.body.id;
         try {
           const updateData=await userModel.updateOne(user_id,
             { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email ,number: req.body.number,ProfileImageDestination : req.body.image},
         );
           res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
           res.end({ status: true ,updateData});
         } catch (e) {
           console.log(e);
           res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
           res.end({ status: false, message: "Something Went Wrong" });
         }
       })()
      });
      return req.pipe(busboy);    
    });
```

Comment: Please show the code that builds the `data` variable you're sending via `axios.post()` from the client.

Comment: jfriend00 Updated